# In golf, can you theoreticaly keep increasing the length of the driver club to get longer drives?

Tags: golf

Driver clubs are about 45.5 inches. So say you practice a ton with that, and hit accurate shots with it. Then wouldn't increasing the length of the club (say, to 46.5) allow you to hit farther? Albeit, you'll be less accurate, but that can be overcome with more practice, yeah? And can't you keep compounding on this idea? To the point that people use the longest club that they can hit with with reasonable accuracy?

Or am I getting the physics wrong? Or is there some regulation on club length that makes this impossible?

In baseball, I understand why one wouldn't use a heavier/longer bat, since you have to react properly to a pitch. But in a golf drive, there's no reacting, so I'm not sure why you wouldn't go longer/heavier, even if it sacrifices accuracy a bit (and accuracy can be worked on).

P.S.: I know that at some point, physically, the length will be too much and make the club too heavy (no one is going to use a 20 foot club). But 45 inches doesn't seem near that physical limit to me, which is why I ask.

Answer (score 2):

> Albeit, you'll be less accurate, but that can be overcome with more practice, yeah?

Apparently not.  At least not to the extent that the extra distance makes up for it.

From [HIREKO Golf](https://www.hirekogolf.com/blog/post/know-the-rules-maximum-golf-club-length):

> However, very few golfers, at least on the PGA and LPGA tour use a
> driver longer than 46" already.  Those that come to mind are Bryson
> DeChambeau and Phil Mickelson.
>
> If it is a big advantage between the current maximum of length of 48"
> and 46", then why don't more experiment or wield a longer driver on
> national TV?  The answer to that is simply risk versus reward.   It is
> frankly much harder to control a longer driver and at the speeds these
> elite golfers possess, any small error is compounded meaning a missed
> fairway, ball underneath an obstacle or ball out of bounds.